# Where does the edit form get it's instance variable from when using scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In scaffolding an application with rails, the new action needs to create a new record instance:

```
def new
  @greeting = Greeting.new
end
```

This is how the initial form gets established for the new view, which uses `form_for @greeting`
Likewise, with the create action we have:

```
def create
  @greeting = Greeting.new(greeting_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @greeting.save
      format.html { redirect_to @greeting, notice: 'Greeting was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @greeting }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @greeting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

That passes in the form data from strong params, creates a new instance and saves it.  Yet when it comes to the edit action we have nothing:

```
def edit
end
```

The view just renders the form in the _form.html.erb file.  Everything makes sense up to this point for me except this:

In the _form.html.erb file you have this:

```
form_for(@greeting) do |f|
```

It's this `@greeting` that I don't get.  Where is the form getting this @greeting variable from if it's not in the edit action?  I originally thought it might be sharing between actions somehow but I am not able to share instance variables between actions (I actually tried creating an instance variable in another action and then rendering it in the view and it didn't work).  I then thought there might be something in my application controller, but this is what my application controller looks like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Basically there doesn't seem to be any logical place that edit is obtaining this @greeting variable data.  I also noticed that the edit form comes pre-populated with the data that's already in the database.  Can anybody explain what is going on here?  Why is this @greeting form not pulling an error?  Why is it pre-populated with the users data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance variable is initialized in a `before_action` filter, which is called before the controller action.

I've stripped away all the irrelevant bits:

```
class GreetingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_greeting, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def edit
  end

  private
  def set_greeting
    @greeting = Greeting.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Even though it seems to be the Rails way, I'd recommend against this practice because it can be unclear where things are coming from.

Instead I usually do something like this:

```
class GreetingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_greeting, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def edit
    @greeting = find_greeting
  end

  private
  def find_greeting
    Greeting.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

It's a little more verbose, but also a lot clearer.

You can read how controller filters work in the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the form getting this @greeting variable from if it's not in
>   the edit action?

If you look into controller there will be a `before_action` filter something like this

```
before_action :set_greeting, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_greeting
  @greeting = Greeting.find(params[:id])
end
```

So, `set_greeting` is responsible for setting the `@greeting` which is the one being used in the edit form.